# Append rows in pandas after a fixed location

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big csv file which has column like `date`, `patient_id` ,`time`.According to some condition I got a specific row in the dataframe-

```
df4=df3.loc[(df3['identity']==ID) & (df3['Date'] == date) & (df3['Time'] ==matched_time )]
```

Now I have another dataframe which has some specific no of rows.Now I want to create a new dataframe which has all the rows after the df4 row I got till all the rows of the second dataframe are over.

example-

```
111_&   14436   16025   6   433050  11/1/2013   13:32:30
111_&   14437   16026   6   433080  11/1/2013   13:33:00
111_&   14438   16027   6   433110  11/1/2013   13:33:30
111_&   14439   16028   6   433140  11/1/2013   13:34:00
111_&   14440   16029   6   433170  11/1/2013   13:34:30
111_&   14441   16030   6   433200  11/1/2013   13:35:00
111_&   14442   16031   6   433230  11/1/2013   13:35:30
111_&   14443   16032   6   433260  11/1/2013   13:36:00
111_&   14444   16033   6   433290  11/1/2013   13:36:30
111_&   14445   16034   6   433320  11/1/2013   13:37:00
```

now according to some condition I get the row `111_&   14440   16029   6   433170  11/1/2013   13:34:30`

Now I want to generate a new dataframe which has the same no of rows as the second dataframe(lets say it has 4 rows)
then it becomes-

```
111_&   14440   16029   6   433170  11/1/2013   13:34:30
111_&   14441   16030   6   433200  11/1/2013   13:35:00
111_&   14442   16031   6   433230  11/1/2013   13:35:30
111_&   14443   16032   6   433260  11/1/2013   13:36:00
```

Comment: Please give an example for input and output.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? It's hard to follow which DataFrame `another dataframe` `new dataframe` `df4`, `df3` and `second dataframe` are.

Comment: @ALollz I added the examples

Comment: I think you just want `df[idx:idx+len(df2)]`

Comment: Or just `df[idx:]`

Answer (score 0):

```
# note this just takes the first index, you may want to check that your condition
# returns a unique row, like:
# assert df3.loc[(df3['identity'] == ID) & (df3['Date'] == date) & (df3['Time'] == matched_time)].shape[0] == 1

idx = df3.loc[(df3['identity'] == ID) & (df3['Date'] == date) & (df3['Time'] == matched_time)].index.item()
result = df3[idx:]
```